# Creating dummy object with values with OCMOCK

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

It was my first time i was trying to use OCMOCK framework for testing my `iOS` application and i have some confusion about it.

Lets say i have a class name called `School` and i want to test it. This class contains students. Lets say i want to start the school by adding a student, so i do some thing like this `School *school = [School alloc] initWithOneStudent:student];`

Now Student Class is like this.

```
@interface Student : NSObject 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lastName;

@end
```

Now how i can get a student object in my test case which has some values for `firstName` and `lastName` when i mock it to pass it to `initWithOneStudent`

I just made up this example, so please excuse if you don't like this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your test case you can make it like below

```
- (void)testCase {
    id mockStudent = OCMClassMock([Student class]);
    OCMStub([mockStudent firstName]).andReturn(@"firstName");
    OCMStub([mockStudent lastName]).andReturn(@"lastName");

    School *school = [School alloc] initWithOneStudent:mockStudent];

    XCTAssertNotNil(school);
    XCTAssertEqual(school.student.firstName, @"firstName");
    XCTAssertEqual(school.student.lastName, @"lastName");
}
```